# Access ReactiveVar // Template.instance() from helper (indirectly)

Tags: meteor, spacebars

How can I access `ReactiveVar` in the construction like below?

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    user: {
        ...
        gender: () => Template.instance().genderFlag.get(), //returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'genderFlag' of null
        ...
    },
});
```

Returns `error` because `Template.instance()` inside `gender:` is `null` (when I `console.log(Template.instance());`)

This is how I create ReactiveVar:

```
Template.profile.onCreated( function() {
  this.genderFlag = new ReactiveVar(0);
});
```

P.S. `gender` is inside `user` because I use `user` context i.e. `{{#with user}}` in my .html.

**UPDATE:**

Spacebars part:

```
<button type="button" name="Male" class="{{#if gender '1'}}gender--selected{{/if}}">Male</button>
<button type="button" name="Female" class="{{#if gender '2'}}gender--selected{{/if}}">Female</button>
```

so I am passing `arg` to the `Template.helper` `gender`:

```
user: {
   ...
   gender: (arg) => arg == Template.instance().genderFlag.get(),
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a function within the helper it seems to be picking up the wrong data context and therefore the Template variable is not available a the time it is called, the following code works, it moves the function to the helper itself so the context is correct and it can access `Template.instance()` correctly, then you can return an object for user as needed for your `#with`

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  user: () => { 
    return { 
        ...
        gender: Template.instance().genderFlag.get() 
        ...
    };
  }
});
```

EDIT:

In line with the update to your question, couple of options but neatest I would say is:

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  user: () => { 
    var gend = Template.instance().genderFlag.get();
    return { 
        ...
        gender: gend,
        isMale: gend===1?"gender--selected":"",
        isFemale: gend===2?"gender--selected":"",
        ...
    };
  }
});
```

And in your handlebars

```
<button type="button" name="Male" class="{{isMale}}">Male</button> 
<button type="button" name="Female" class="{{isFemale}}">Female</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works in construction like you suggest, but I also (sorry, did not mention that in my question) should be able to pass `arg` from spacebar `if`like so: **please refer to the updated question**

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! (only instead var I use let)